# JavaScript: is extending prototype dynamically a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, prototype, extends

I want to know if extending a Function's prototype dynamically is a bad practice. I'm considering to do this using a static method that receives the property name and the function to add to the prototype.

Is that a bad practice?

```
function Test() {
    this.condition = false;
}

Test.extend = function(id, task) {
    this.prototype[id] = function() {
        return task.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

Comment: Only if you abuse it to the point where keeping track is hard (which, frankly, is usually what happens). Personally, I prefer to not reach that level of meta in my programming.

Comment: It's a bad practice because your code doesn't work :-) It would need to be `task` instead of `this.task`, and should be shortened to `this.prototype[id] = task;`

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess there are some performance issues with `.apply`.

Comment: @Rajesh performance issues with apply? Since when? Not to mention the fact that this whole thing assumes modifying prototypes dynamically, which has waaay bigger perf implications that using `Function.prototype.apply`...

Comment: This practice, *the way you've presented it*, is a bad idea: just adding random methods to prototypes that insta-modify every existing object created by a given constructor. Nor is the `.apply` necessary. Generally speaking, as a *rule of thumb*, inheritance is bad. Inheritance that is not visible by glancing at the source code is worse. And prototypal inheritance is still inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is bad practice in this instance, as you have no control over if an [id] method being added gets overidden from within the class.

```
var test = new Test();
test.extend("example", function() {
    console.log("First Method");
});

test.extend("example", function() {
    console.log("Second Method");
});
```

With how your code is, you have no way of knowing when the first method gets overidden and thus randomly breaking your code.

Comment: Well, this can be solved checking the methods added to the prototype before adding a new one. But if you have this check, extending the prototype this way is a bad practice?